# How to fix that stmt->execute() always returns false?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on a php project with a database. I want users to be able to comment articles (I have already a working system for article creation) but I cannot insert the comments in the database. Here is the code:

```
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$content = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'new_entry', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$author = $_SESSION["username"];
$article_id = $_GET['article'];
$rating = 0;

if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `entries` (`article_id`, `rating`, `content`, `author`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    $insert_stmt->bind_param('iiss', $article_id, $rating, $content, $author);
    // Führe die vorbereitete Anfrage aus.
    if ($insert_stmt->execute()) {
        header('Location: success.php');
    } else {
      header('Location: failure.php');
    }
}
```

This is always directing me to 'failure.php' - what is the problem here?

I thank you in advance!

Comment: I suggest you take a look into your http servers error log file and use the error handling features the `mysqli` class offers.

Comment: Check errors with http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php

Comment: I am getting this error: `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: article in C:\MAMP\htdocs\index.php on line 30`

Comment: Is `article` pass from query string? OR may be you need to use POST : `$article_id = $_POST['article'];`

Comment: @b. desai `article` is written in the url like `localhost/index.php?article=5` but `$_GET['article']` is always returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because You have,

```
$article_id = $_GET['article'];
```

in your code, While you are POSTing the form data,
So your `$article` is `null` or `""`.
That's why it is redirecting to `failure.php`.

Instead use,

```
$article_id = $_POST['article'];
```

Comment: see the comment below the question. Its already stated that `article` is getting from `localhost/index.php?article=5`

Comment: I thank you! Your answer gave me the idea for my own solution.

Comment: If this answer helps mark it as an answer instead of answering your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for the incovenience I caused, but I found a solution myself.
Instead of getting the article_id from GET directly, I created a hidden input field with its value:

`<input type="hidden" name="article" value="<?php echo $_GET['article'] ?>">`

Now I can access this value with POST, what works perfectly:

`$article_id = $_POST['article'];`

I hope that I could help anyone with this!

Comment: If others answer(s) in your question helps, mark it as an answer instead of answering your own question.